# Why can't I install lxml for python?

Tags: python, lxml

I have downloaded the tarball for lxml and am using ipython setup.py install to try to install it. Unfortunately it is giving me screenfuls of error messages:

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200651: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_OPERAND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200661: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200671: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_ARITY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200681: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_CTXT_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200691: error: ‘XML_XPATH_INVALID_CTXT_POSITION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200921: error: ‘LIBXSLT_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200933: error: ‘xsltLibxsltVersion’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200945: error: ‘__pyx_v_4lxml_5etree_XSLT_DOC_DEFAULT_LOADER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200945: error: ‘xsltDocDefaultLoader’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200954: error: ‘xsltDocLoaderFunc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200954: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_doc_loader’
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Apparently cython can interfere with installation, but I don't have cython installed on my system. This is on a centos 6.4 operating system, with ipython running 2.7.

Comment: Do you have python header development install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lxml depends on `libxml2` and `libxslt`. Use yum to install the development headers:

```
yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel
```