# Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip

Tags: python

I'm getting an error `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?` when trying to install lxml through pip.

```
  c:\users\f\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitqjzysz.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\f\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I don't find any libxml2 dev packages to install via pip.

Using Python 2.7 and Python 3.x on x86 in a virtualenv under Windows 10.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Install lxml from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) for your python version. It's a precompiled WHL with required modules/dependencies.

The site lists several packages, when e.g. using Win32 Python 3.11, use `lxml‑4.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win32.whl`.

Download the file, and then install with:

```
pip install C:\path\to\downloaded\file\lxml‑4.9.0‑cp311‑cp311‑win32.whl
```

Comment: a not for people having the same problem: 3.4.4. will result in the same error. only version 3.5.0 has gotten me rid of it

Comment: @user151496 - yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel did this for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884514/why-cant-i-install-lxml-for-python

Comment: You can also install with this more generic command: pip install --use-wheel --find-links=C:\path\to\folder\with\wheel lxml

Comment: Perfectly installed under Python 2.7 and W10.

Comment: you should switch to linux

Comment: I have solved my problem installing `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt-dev` in Fedora

Comment: Great help. Another small thing I needed to do: It failed to install on my virtual env (wheel not supported). Eventually I've installed it on my regular python (c:\program files x86...) and copied the `python27\lib\site-packages\lxml*` folders to the virtual env.

Comment: gave me `lxml... is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: @Inspi, match it with Python version installed. For Python version 3.11 it is `-cp311-`.

Comment: @Inspi: ensure you're using the right Python version and ensure you're using the right platform (Win32 <-> 64). Also this can be caused by an outdated PIP, so do a `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Excellent. I used amd64 version, and it worked on Windows 10 machine Thank you.

Comment: It seems like https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is no longer updated. It says "Archived".

Answer (score 168):

I had this issue and realised that whilst I did have libxml2 installed, I didn't have the necessary development libraries required by the python package. Installing them solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: Please read through the OPs content. He is doing this on a Windows machine!

Comment: Correct solution for linux when using pip

Comment: **Fedora 23:** `dnf install libxml2-devel` and `dnf install libxslt-devel`

Comment: @Metahuman Installing the same packages with the Cygwin installer solves the problem for me on Windows 10.

Comment: **Centos 7**: ``sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel``
(required for python-docx module)

Answer (score 38):

Try to use:
`easy_install lxml`
That works for me, win10, python 2.7.

Comment: it throws the same error when using easy install command for lxml

Comment: Used to work for me, but now with a new lxml version this no longer works.

Answer (score 28):

On Mac OS X El Capitan I had to run these two commands to fix this error:

```
xcode-select --install
pip install lxml
```

Which ended up installing lxml-3.5.0

When you run the xcode-select command you may have to sign a EULA (so have an X-Term handy for the UI if you're doing this on a headless machine).

Comment: Yup, that do the trick for me in OS X El Capitan. In fact, if you scrolls up the screen to see the root cause of the error, there is a line there says "Perhaps try: xcode-select --install"

Comment: This fixed it, and there is a line that does suggest this as commented above!

Comment: Does anyone else feel like they've run `xcode-select --install` before, though? Is there any introspection on what this does either a first or second time? As a note, though I did not have to install `lxml` globally for it to work in a virtual environment, so at least there is that.

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone else has the same issue as this on

> Centos, try:

```
yum install python-lxml
```

> Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-lxml
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

```
set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
```

run this command instead, must have VS C++ compiler installed first

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

It works for me with Python 3.5.2 and Windows 7

Comment: i have vc2017 installation, trying your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried install a lib that depends `lxml` and nothing works. I see a message when build was started: "Building without Cython", so after install `cython` with `apt-get install cython`, `lxml` was installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and realized that while I did have libxml2 installed, I didn't have the necessary development libraries required by the python package.

**1)** Installing them solved the problem:

**The site to download the file**: [Download](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

**2)** After Installing the file save it in a accessible folder

```
pip install *path to that file*
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to include more than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it doesn't work in python 3.11, but 3.10 works.

On windows, to install a module with a previous version, use

```
py -3.10 -m pip install lxml
```

if you want to install it in a venv, then use

```
py -3.10 -m venv .venv
.venv/Scripts/pip.exe install lxml
```

if you've set up the venv, then you can just use

```
pip install lxml
```

You also need to run the python program with that version. If you set up a venv, then you don't need to do this.

```
py -3.10 file.py
```

Comment: `py -3.10 -m pip install lxml` gave me the exact same error

Comment: Are you using python 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

It is not strange for me that none of the solutions above came up, but I saw how the igd installation removed the new version and installed the old one, for the solution I downloaded this archive:https://pypi.org/project/igd/#files

and changed the recommended version of the new version: 'lxml==4.3.0' in setup.py
It works!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for python 32 bit. After install 64bit, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Big Sur, I ran `xcode-select --install` as suggested, installed XCode, restarted the Mac, and was still getting the same error when installing `lxml`.

What helped was to reset the XCode path:

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

After that, `lxml` installed successfully.

Comment: why would you give a Mac answer to an almost 8 year old Windows question? very confused..

Comment: @AndreGreeff I just had the same problem myself, and I'm on Mac, so I spent some time researching it and wanted to share my answer for people having the same problem. I know that the question is about Windows, but I see other non-Windows answers, so I thought mine can be helpful as well.

Comment: fair enough.. in hindsight, I guess this also helps to show future visitors that there was "more recent" activity on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download the compiled WHL provided on GitHub project release page https://github.com/lxml/lxml/releases

Them install using the pip command

```
python -m pip install --upgrade path/to/lxml.whl
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using `venv`.

In my case it was enough to add `lxml==4.6.3` to `requirements.txt`.

One library wanted earlier version and this was causing this error, so when I forced pip to use newest version (currently 4.6.3) installation was successful.