# Can't install python lxml (and libxml2) on windows

Tags: python, windows, lxml, libxml2

I'm trying to install lxml on windows (pip install lxml) but i keep getting following error:

```
*****
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
****************************************************************************

Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Us
ers\\meme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-m_doxfaj\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(comp
ile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fi
le__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\meme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ekkhc0id
-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed
 with error code 1 in C:\Users\meme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m_doxfaj\lxml
```

I've tried to download a binary files for windows from here (ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/) and adding them to path but it doesn't seem to help.

Manual download lxml wheel(http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml for cp34) file also fails upon trying to install with the following error log:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 242, in move_wheel_files
    name, user=user, home=home, root=root, isolated=isolated
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\locations.py", line 182, in distutils_scheme
    d.parse_config_files()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 394, in parse_config_files
    parser.read(filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 672, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 993, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 2193: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm using python34 32bit on x64 win7 machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).
First do `pip install wheel` and then `pip install <filename.whl>` to install the downloaded binary.