# Trouble installing lxml with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am trying to install this library on Mac OSx 10.11 using this command:

```
sudo -H pip install lxml
```

While I keep getting this message:

```
#include "libxml/xpath.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Yet I am pretty sure that libxml2 is installed here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2
```

I used brew to install this package. There shouldn't be any problem. How should I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't link libxml and libxslt to avoid conflicts. You need to `--force` them.

```
brew link libxml2 --force
brew link libxslt --force
```

I faced this problem when I upgraded to latest OS X. I wrote a [blog post](http://masnun.com/2015/07/14/fixing-lxml-installation-on-os-x.html) on it detailing the issue.