# pip install libxml2 failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install `libxml2` since I came to know this is dependency for `lxml`. Facing issues like:

```
Could not find dependencies
```

Any idea how to install `libxml2`?

My python version is 3.5.2.

Comment: OS version? Are you using Linux, Windows or OSX?

Comment: lxml2 is not a Python package, it's a system lib. How to install it depends on your system.

Answer (score 18):

[Official documentation](http://lxml.de/installation.html) has the installation steps for Linux, Mac OS and Windows.

To install lxml on Ubuntu, you first will need to install the binary dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

Then you will be able to install lxml using pip:

```
pip install lxml
```

You cannot install `libxml` or `libxslt` using pip as they are not Python packages.

Comment: To install it on non-Ubuntu Linux systems, check the comments on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872362/4995840