# Scrapy Installation - Issue with lxml install

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml, libxml2, failed-installation

I am new to Python and I am trying to install scrapy, I have python 2.7.12 and pip 8.1.2 on windows 10. when I give the command 'pip install scrapy' it tries to install lxml and gives the below error. I downloaded the libxml2 binary, extracted to a folder and added the bin folder in path variable.But still the same issue. Please guide me with this issue, I am stuck with this. The error message is mentioned below.

```
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
lxml.etree.c
src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
Compile failed: command 'C:\\Users\\myuserid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
creating users
creating users\myuser~1
creating users\myuser~1\appdata
creating users\myuser~1\appdata\local
creating users\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp
C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /Tcc:\users\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInita7i8_a.c /Fousers\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInita7i8_a.obj
xmlXPathInita7i8_a.c
c:\users\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInita7i8_a.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'C:\\Users\\myuserid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------

Command "c:\softwares\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\myuser~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-m4bvsr\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-dnttln-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\myuser~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-m4bvsr\lxml\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use one of these [whl files](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), based on your system.

After download it, use these command in where you download that file:

```
pip install ***.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy's docummentation [recommends using Anaconda](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda) to install the package. Lxml package is really tricky to install on windows and anaconda is a really straigh-forward shortcut.

There's also unnoficial binaries of lxml [mentioned in lxml's docummentation](http://lxml.de/installation.html#ms-windows) that you can use to install already compiled lxml package. There are more instructions as well, how to install lxml on windows os there too.

Answer (score 0):

What version of pip do you have?
Just upgrading pip helps in my case

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```