# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

Tags: python, scrapy

so I'm on Python 3.5.2, I'm trying to install scrapy, it throws an error saying

> Failed building wheel for lxml 
>  Could not find function
>   xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

So I try installing lxml, it throws the same error. I try installing it from [Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), it says:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32 (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32

I can install almost nothing with pip. I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Note that it works flawlessly on my ubunto machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`pip install lxml==3.6.0`

Comment: I found this still encountered the same problem :/

`Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?`

Answer (score 2):

I tried
`sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev`
and that seems to resolve the issue I had.

Comment: Sure you can `apt-get` on a W10 machine.

Comment: how can we run apt-get on windows

Answer (score 0):

MS Windows 10 Pro 64-bit build 1607

> pip3 install lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

works in my case

Comment: I am facing same problem with libxml2 (for mtmproxy install), and even if i've installed the libxml2-python along lxml (this works) i always get that error. I should give a try to Python3 :-/ A difference between you and the asker, is the arch x64 vs x86. I don't think that the Windows build should do that much difference.

Comment: `ERROR: lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`