# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2 while executing pip install uspto-opendata-python

Tags: python, libxml2

I have conda xml2 installed.

However, when I execute `pip install uspto-opendata-python`, I get the following message

> could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. is libxml2
> installed?

I noticed a similar question here - [Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092570/could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2-installed) - but the suggestions listed there are not resolving my issue.

how to resolve this issue? That's the error message i'm getting:

> C:\Users\njind\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitwd5ud9xh.c(1): fatal
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file
> or directory
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit code 2
>
> Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2
> installed?

[image]

Comment: Error message picture is unreadable. Please [edit] your question and include it as text, formatted like code with the `{ }` button.

Comment: Thank you, BoarGules. I have added the error message in text format within {} but I am not sure if it coming like a code.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. You must download the file from
[Archived: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), then install it like this on Windows:

`pip install C:\Users\USER\Downloads\lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`