# *.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python

Recently, i have faced with the below error:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444671/installing-lxml-libxml2-libxslt-for-python-3-5-on-windows-10), and decided to install the `*.whl` using `pip` command based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file).
I am trying to install it using this command:

```
pip install lxml-4.3.3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

But it complains with:

```
lxml-4.3.3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

My python version is:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0a1

Windows 10, 64 bit
```

How can i fix it?
Should i uninstall my python and install `2.7`?

Comment: What operating system are you using where you run this command? I suspect that you are using 64 bit Windows, but that wheel is for 32 bit Windows.

Comment: @ritlew yes, i use 64 windows 10, but it seems that, there is no wheel for 64 Win in this link? https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libxml-python

Answer (score 2):

Read the answers:

> cp35 in file name means version for Python 3.5.

You have Python 3.8 and install version for 2.7.
Also the architecture has to match the architecture of your Python version. Which is amd64 or win32

Comment: It looks like there is no `lxml` release for python 3.8... You might try the one for `cp37`, `windows` and `amd64` and see what happens