# Getting an error when i try to install a package (translate) by "pip3 install translate" in virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am facing an error when i am trying to install a package in my python project virtual environment. But it's OK when i try to install the same package by same commend (pip3 install translate) in outside of the virtual environment.

> pip 19.0.3
>   Python 3.8.2

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/b2/2ea329a07bbc0c7227eef84ca89ffd6895e7ec237d6c0b26574d56103e53/translate-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Requirement already satisfied: tox in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from translate) (3.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pre-commit in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from translate) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from translate) (7.1.1)
Collecting lxml (from translate)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/2b/0a66d5436f237aff76b91e68b4d8c041d145ad0a2cdeefe2c42f76ba2857/lxml-4.5.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from translate) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml>=0.9.4 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.4.1; platform_system == "Windows" in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv!=20.0.0,!=20.0.1,!=20.0.2,!=20.0.3,!=20.0.4,!=20.0.5,!=20.0.6,!=20.0.7,>=16.0.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (20.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.14.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: py<2,>=1.4.17 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1,>=0.12.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tox->translate) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cfgv>=2.0.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from pre-commit->translate) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: identify>=1.0.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from pre-commit->translate) (1.4.15)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from pre-commit->translate) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nodeenv>=0.11.1 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from pre-commit->translate) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->translate) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->translate) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->translate) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->translate) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv!=20.0.0,!=20.0.1,!=20.0.2,!=20.0.3,!=20.0.4,!=20.0.5,!=20.0.6,!=20.0.7,>=16.0.0->tox->translate) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv!=20.0.0,!=20.0.1,!=20.0.2,!=20.0.3,!=20.0.4,!=20.0.5,!=20.0.6,!=20.0.7,>=16.0.0->tox->translate) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in e:\testproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=14->tox->translate) (2.4.7)
Installing collected packages: lxml, translate
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command E:\TestProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muzepxbu\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0023ymbj\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\TestProject\venv\include\site\python3.8\lxml:
    Building lxml version 4.5.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

```
Using build configuration of libxslt
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\html
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml
copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\lxml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IE:\TestProject\venv\include -IC:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
etree.c
c:\users\rabby\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-muzepxbu\lxml\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
creating Users
creating Users\rabby
creating Users\rabby\AppData
creating Users\rabby\AppData\Local
creating Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitt0q8ob77.c /FoUsers\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitt0q8ob77.obj
xmlXPathInitt0q8ob77.c
C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitt0q8ob77.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************

----------------------------------------
```

Command "E:\TestProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muzepxbu\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0023ymbj\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\TestProject\venv\include\site\python3.8\lxml" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rabby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-muzepxbu\lxml\

Comment: have you checked this line 
" Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"

kindly check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785756/2544875

Comment: also try to groom the error message as it's sooo lone for the question

Comment: thanks @KerolosWilliam, i didn't check that line.
then i have installed lxml package and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by installing lxml package in my virtual environment.

```
easy_install lxml
```