# Cannot install lxml

Tags: python

When I'm trying to install lxml just like `pip install lxml` I'm getting an error " Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?".

I found a similar issue [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2),  but when I'm trying to solve the problem following that advice I'm getting another error `lxml-4.5.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` The path to the wheel is `D:\whl\lxml-4.5.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Using Python 3.8.1 under Windows 10 x64

Comment: Is libxml2 installed though?

Comment: @EthanM-H
getting an error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xo8f_3dq\libxml2-python3\" while trying to install like pip install libxml2

Comment: `pip install libxml2-python3` maybe?

Comment: @EthanM-H the same :(

Comment: Actually just properly read that error in ur comment, update your setuptools like so `pip install -U setuptools` and retry your pip install :)
You may also need to update `wheel`

Comment: @EthanM-H I've already done that. No results

Answer (score 0):

I`ve solved the problem!

The error occurred in PyCharm editor. Then I tried to install lxml in VS Code editor and it was done successfully. IDK why the problem occurred, but after reinstalling PyCharm everything was OK

BTW if reinstalling didn't help, try to follow advice by Ethan in the comments