# LXML neither downloading nor binding in Windows 10

Tags: python, lxml

This is problem I get. Went to a link this forum suggested, downloaded new version, hit it. Will not bind to LXML or claim the drives. Not sure what to do.

Even downloaded Visual Studio, downloaded the version of C++ even though I had 14.2, wants 14.0.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.5.2.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for lxml, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: lxml
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t0wyzrg1\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t0wyzrg1\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hegt7ofw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t0wyzrg1\lxml\
    Complete output (94 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.5.2.
    Building without Cython.
    Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\program files\python39\include -Ic:\program files\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    etree.c
    c:\program files\python39\include\pyconfig.h(201): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    creating Users
    creating Users\Asus
    creating Users\Asus\AppData
    creating Users\Asus\AppData\Local
    creating Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt /TcC:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInith9x_zgkr.c /FoUsers\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInith9x_zgkr.obj
    xmlXPathInith9x_zgkr.c
    C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInith9x_zgkr.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t0wyzrg1\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t0wyzrg1\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hegt7ofw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I'm super sad and want to give up, been on a deadline. Tried using WOrdpress scrapers, won't work. 
I even downloaded C++ and Visual Studio 8( with 14.0 installed, no go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Comment: No wheel would install, no twisted, no lxml, no libxml2. Nothing. Retrograded from installing 3.8.6. 3.9 refused to work. I messaged a successful Python coder on Fiverr, over 500 feedbacks charges minimum 250, asked him some questions before that. Came to a problem, offered to pay said no "try this". Man today was a win n n half

Comment: How were you trying to install them, what command(s) did you execute?

Answer (score -1):

I downgraded Python from 3.9 to 3.8.6, all libs work now.