# I can't install Snscrape

Tags: python

I want to install the snscrape library for Python, but I'm getting an error like the one below. What should I do?I made the necessary path paths and pip installation. I also installed c++ from the visual studio compiler. But every time I get the same error.
......................................
......................................

````
     command: 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\beded\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n3okvgk7\\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\beded\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n3okvgk7\\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8tg2om0k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n3okvgk7\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\
    Complete output (94 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.6.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IC:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
    cl: Komut sat\x8dr\x8d warning D9025: '/W3', '/w' ile ge‡ersiz k\x8dl\x8dn\x8dyor
    etree.c
    C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n3okvgk7\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    creating Users
    creating Users\beded
    creating Users\beded\AppData
    creating Users\beded\AppData\Local
    creating Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /TcC:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitkqndyawb.c /FoUsers\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitkqndyawb.obj
    xmlXPathInitkqndyawb.c
    C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitkqndyawb.c(1): fatal error C1083: i‡erme dosyas\x8d a‡\x8dlam\x8dyor: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\beded\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n3okvgk7\\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\beded\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n3okvgk7\\lxml_728b6ac96c6d481282c38d936b296c7f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8tg2om0k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\beded\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: The error at the end is: "*Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?*". Have you checked that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Answer (score -1):

Try
pip install snscrape --user --upgrade

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :(